# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' - visual studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm using sql server 2005 and visual studio 2013, the following problem happens when i want to create a new database connection in visual studio. I have searched through other posts then tried their method, but still the problem cannot be solved, please help! thks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as Adminitrator

Comment: haha why i didnt think of that, yes simply running vs as admin, it works! thks man!